# Google Server Authentication Code makes the sign in fail

Tags: java, android, api, authentication, drive

So I managed to make the new google sign in work using

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
            .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .build();
```

And it works great, but now I need the Authentication code to send to my server, the problem is that when I add this line `.requestServerAuthCode(CLIENTID)` to the GoogleSignInOption, the sign in fails, giving a useless status code `Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12500, resolution=null}`
I already set up the OAUTH and I use the correct client id. What could be the cause?

Comment: Try using .requestServerAuthCode(CLIENTID,true) ! It will force you to give auth code.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure in **Firebase** or the **Google Console API** your Android Client ID and provide the keystore signature and your package name.

Check which is the fingerprint of your keystore which you use to sign the apk. Beware that you might be using a debug.keystore or a release keystore. If you are using Android studio you can check in Build Types/Signing.

Most of the time this issues have to do with a bad configuration of the ClientIDs and the ServerID.

To find your server ID, check the 'Web client Id'  in the API Console. Also check that this ID is the one you are using on your backend server.